# Authenticating with Active Directory using user log-on name instead of display name

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, ldapconnection

I am writing a program in C++ that connects to an Active Directory server, searches for content, and then dumps that content to terminal. My problem has been that the only way I have been able to succesfully authenticate and connect is with a user's display name (E.g. Test User). I would like to change this authentication method to use the user's logon name instead. (E.g. tuser@example.com)

Here is the code that is responsible for setting up the session:

```
char * _hostName = "The_Computer_Name";
char * _dn = "CN=Test User,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM";
char * _ps = "The_Password123";

int ldap_Query::session_init(){

    if (_pLdapConnection != nullptr) return 0;

    _pLdapConnection = ldap_init(_hostName, LDAP_PORT);
    if ( _pLdapConnection == nullptr) {
        int err = ldap_get_option(_pLdapConnection, LDAP_OPT_ERROR_NUMBER, &err);
        throw LdapQueryException(ldap_err2string(err));
        }


    unsigned long lRtn = ldap_simple_bind_s(_pLdapConnection, _dn,_ps);
    if (lRtn != LDAP_SUCCESS) {
        ldap_unbind(_pLdapConnection);
        _pLdapConnection = nullptr;
        throw LdapQueryException(ldap_err2string(lRtn));
        }

    return 0;
}
```

I think what i'm looking for is called the User-Principal-Name, but have not seen an example of using this to authenticate. I've tried just replacing _dn with "CN=tuser,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM", but have had no luck with that.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do an ldap bind with the upn name directly.

When you do a simple bind to the directory via ldap you need to use the fully qualified DN of the user you are binding as and their password.

To use the `userprincipalname` the way you want you need to search for the user either with a service account or anonymously (if it is allowed) with their supplied `userprincipalname` attribute.

Search with something like this.

```
(&(objectclass=user)(userprincipalname=<supplied value>))
```

Get the DN from the resulting user entry if you get a match and then bind the user.

Comment: Could you clarify "you need to search for the user either with a service account or anonymously (if it is allowed) with their supplied userprincipalname attribute."? Does this mean, I need to try and authenticate with an administrator account or make an attempt to connect with no credentials first, then perform a search with that filter? It seems like I might as well just perform a search for records using those credentials instead of trying to authenticate as a user.

Comment: yes, you need to be bound to the directory so that you can search it.  Some directories will be configured to permit anonymous bind and may return a subset of attributes to an anonymous bind.  This is not typical with Active Directory.  You generally need to bind with a service account that can search so you can find the user.  You are in a catch 22 with using the user's credentials to do this though;  you need a DN to perform a bind but you can't get the DN until you bind.  Typically an app will have an open connection to the directory server to search for users.

Comment: If you head towards more Windows centric tooling you can achieve binds directly with the upn, DOMAIN\username but you give up the flexibility of LDAP a bit at that point.

Comment: I came across this post...[Accessing Active Directory Using C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956355/accessing-active-directory-using-c?rq=1) Where the user just passed in a "user@mydomain.com" string. I tried this using my credentials instead of building a DN. I'm not sure if this is correct or secure...but it seemed to work.

Comment: Good to know. I am guessing there is some native windows code in there that is handling that for you.  I would just make sure you can search, etc with the bound account like you would expect and that it has not stepped down to an anonymous bind.  As far as secure goes, I would say it is not secure unless your underlying transport mechanism is over TLS to the secure port and not the open port.